# How to Use Named Attribute to Modify Meshes Instanced on Points

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups, instances

I have a geometry node group that creates embroidery. I would like use vertex groups so I can parameterize more of the settings on a per vertex basis.

I'd like these to scale the global parameters I use in my node group. For example there is a height parameter and a width parameter for the whole mesh. On areas where the edges are at an acute angle I'd like the height to be lower than the global height.

So in the picture I'd like the selected point to be 50% height (0.5).

[image]

I also need to control the width of the threads per vertex. Controlling the width when I was using a spline was easy. I used the radius field as seen above. The problem is splines, for whatever reason, have no way to set external attributes like you can with vertex groups so I converted my spline to a mesh and am now trying to use the vertex groups to shape the threads.

How do I use my vertex groups set values to modify the threads I'm instancing on points?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well... the logical method I had envisioned of crafting the threads I wanted before instancing them on my mesh does not work.

The workflow of geometry nodes does not work like that apparently.

You have to instance the threads on points and then modify them afterward by realizing instances.

So answer is... instance the primitive curve line on points, realize instances, then parameterize your curve lines.